# Android: Using 2 layouts in one layout

Tags: java, android, layout, button, android-framelayout

I have some FrameLayout to display overlapping images. Under this FrameLayout I want to display a standard button for some click-action.

To make my work easier, I thought, I can put a new Linear, or Relative, Layout under the FrameLayout - surely all in one LinearLayout.

But this method isn't working for me.

**What is the best way to show my button under a whole FrameLayout without putting it in the Layout and managing his position programmaticaly?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left" >
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/coverimg"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="top|left"
         android:maxHeight="100dp"
         android:minHeight="130dp"
         android:minWidth="130dp"
         android:src="@drawable/cover_img" />
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first to say:
your orientation of the first LinearLayout is wrong. You should use vertical instead of horizontel, cause it would show the button right of your images and not below.

second:
no nead to wrap the button into another LinearLayout, cause it's a sinlge item and attached to your first LinearLayout.

third:
to set the button on another 'place', give your top LinearLayout an ID like 'android:id="@+id/myLinear"' and then use following code:

```
LinearLayout myLinear = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.myLinear);
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Gravity.CENTER);
myLinear.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

maybe this will work to:

```
LinearLayout myLinear = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.myLinear);
myLinear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Gravity.CENTER));
```

Hope i could help you?

Answer (score 0):

First you change Linear layout orientation to vertical, and second no need to use another

layout u can put button directly

Ex: android:orientation="vertical"